# Backbone overwrite collection.sync for Oauth

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, oauth, yelp

I'm trying to use backbone for a local project that's never going to see a real web server, and which interacts with the Yelp API via AJAX. The Yelp API requires we use oauth to authenticate, and gives [sample code](https://github.com/Yelp/yelp-api/blob/master/v2/js/search.html) that I've modeled my own code after. When I use the sample code, I don't run into any problems with Cross-Origin or anything. However, when I turn off my browser security options I just get a 400 response for errors.

I had tried overwriting the fetch method as follows:

```
fetch: function(options) {
  var accessor, message, parameterMap, parameters;
  if (!options) {
    options = {};
  }
  accessor = {
    consumerSecret: LOAF.auth.conserumerSecret,
    tokenSecret: LOAF.auth.accessTokenSecret
  };
  parameters = [];
  parameters.push(['oauth_consumer_key', LOAF.auth.consumerKey]);
  parameters.push(['oauth_consumer_secret', LOAF.auth.consumerSecret]);
  parameters.push(['oauth_token', LOAF.auth.accessToken]);
  parameters.push(['oauth_signature_method', 'HMAC-SHA1']);
  parameters.push(['location', "New York City"]);
  message = {
    'action': this.url,
    'method': 'GET',
    'parameters': parameters
  };
  OAuth.setTimestampAndNonce(message);
  OAuth.SignatureMethod.sign(message, accessor);
  parameterMap = OAuth.getParameterMap(message.parameters);
  parameterMap.oauth_signature = OAuth.percentEncode(parameterMap.oauth_signature);
  options.url = this.url;
  options.data = parameterMap;
  options.cache = true;
  options.dataType = 'json';
  options.success = this.onResponse;
  console.log("Attempting");
  console.log(options);
  return Backbone.Model.prototype.fetch.apply(this, options);
},
```

but this generates the 400 response. I have a feeling its because I'm not making the AJAX call properly because backbone does most of it for me and is likely overwriting some of the options I'm setting. I think what I need to do is overwrite this collection's "sync" method instead to just handle the OAuth and parse the response myself. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is the proper way to do things, but it works this way, so here's my solution. I override fetch and never call the default fetch method. Instead I make an ajax call in the fetch method, and have an `onResponse` method that handles the response, creating the models (Yelp Businesses) for the response. Hope this helps anyone in the same position.

```
LOAF.YelpList = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  model: LOAF.Business,
  url: 'http://api.yelp.com/v2/search?',
  fetch: function(options) {
    var accessor, message, parameterMap, parameters;
    if (!options) {
      options = {};
    }
    accessor = {
      consumerSecret: LOAF.auth.consumerSecret,
      tokenSecret: LOAF.auth.accessTokenSecret
    };
    parameters = [];
    parameters.push(['callback', 'cb']);
    parameters.push(['oauth_consumer_key', LOAF.auth.consumerKey]);
    parameters.push(['oauth_consumer_secret', LOAF.auth.consumerSecret]);
    parameters.push(['oauth_token', LOAF.auth.accessToken]);
    parameters.push(['oauth_signature_method', 'HMAC-SHA1']);
    parameters.push(['location', "New York City"]);
    message = {
      'action': this.url,
      'method': 'GET',
      'parameters': parameters
    };
    OAuth.setTimestampAndNonce(message);
    OAuth.SignatureMethod.sign(message, accessor);
    parameterMap = OAuth.getParameterMap(message.parameters);
    parameterMap.oauth_signature = OAuth.percentEncode(parameterMap.oauth_signature);
    options.url = this.url;
    options.data = parameterMap;
    options.cache = true;
    options.dataType = 'jsonp';
    options.jsonpCallback = 'cb';
    options.success = this._onResponse;
    options.context = this;
    return $.ajax(options);
  },
  _onResponse: function(data, textStats, xhr) {
    debugger;
    var _this = this;
    return _.each(data.businesses, function(business) {
      var busModel;
      if (!_this.get(business.id)) {
        busModel = new LOAF.Business(business);
        return _this.add(busModel);
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Two things to note:

1. The initial code would have worked but the consumerSecret was spelled wrong, resulting in improper OAuth calls. That's why I was getting a 400 error.
2. Even if you fix this, there's the problem of Cross-Origin calls. Switching to the AJAX method I used alleviates this problem. However, there may exist a way to fix this more native to Backbone. For the time-frame of my project, this would not do.